# Optimization in an HPC Pelican Cluster

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, heuristics

At the institution where I teach, we have a cluster in one of the computer labs using the Pelican HPC Linux distribution. Currently we would like to install Cplex or some other optimization system such as Gurobi on the cluster master computer and run some mathematical models for linear or nonlinear programming problems, heuristics and metaheuristics.

My questions are:

1. Using a cluster, would the processing power for attempted resolution of the proposed problems increase or remain the same?
2. Would I need to program the problems differently from the traditional one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

1. Simply using a solver like Cplex or Gurobi, you are not going to be able to utilize the full processing power available on a large cluster. I believe Gurobi has some capabilities for solving your problem concurrently in independent threads (each using a different solution method), and then stopping when the fastest one finishes. However, you don't need a cluster to use this approach, and the speedup you will see certainly will not scale with the number of cores available on a big cluster. Solving optimization problems in a way that can fully utilize HPC is a difficult area of research. The solutions are often problem dependent, and require specialized decompositions of the original problem.
2. Yes. You will need program with MPI to communicate between nodes that do not share RAM. The easiest way to get started is perhaps using Python and the mpi4py module.

Comment: Both Cplex and Gurobi have "distributed MIP" facilities for solving large MIP problems on different nodes. This can be better than one single large SMP machine as there is less contention. For distributed MIP you don't need to implement a decomposition yourself.

Comment: Do Cplex and Gurobi distribute the branch-and-bound tree or just do a horse race? I was under the impression that it was the latter. If it is the former, do you have experience solving "distributed MIP" on a big cluster? I'm just curious as to what kind of speedup you saw. I.e., how did it scale with the number of cores?

Comment: These are real distributed MIP algorithms (see the Cplex and Gurobi documentation for more information). Yes, I have clients using this with good results. Wrt speedups: this depends (as usual). On some problems we have seen very good speedups, on others not so much. Best thing to do is to try out on your problem with your hardware.